# Java - Android Dialog Box via Opening Button

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

So I have a button with an on click listener. It's supposed to open a dialog window with options... but it doesn't.

Anyone know what the problem is?

```
seeTexts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            }
        });
```

EDIT (UPDATED CODE):

```
seeTexts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't call the `show` method of your `AlertDialog` object

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. I've included an edit to show what I've changed it to.

Comment: Weird... It now seems to work without any change. Sorry - that's weird! Your solution works! Thanks.